# Using Response code or message with get_queryset method in django restframework or custome response

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

Currently I am using django rest framework. In the case of filtering I used an extra ValidationErrorere class to return some extra response. Here is my ProductList class to filter data.

```
class ProductList(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        type   = self.request.query_params.get('type', None)
        if status is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(status=status)
        if type is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(type=type)

        if not queryset:
            raise ValidationError
        return queryset


class ValidationError(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    default_detail = ({ 'response_code': '404', 'response': status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
, 'message': 'No data is available', })
```

Here i used a custom ValidationError class to return some extra value. When there is no data that means queryset returns no data then it shows these output.

```
{
    "response_code": "404",
    "response": "404",
    "message": "No data is available"
}
```

Now It returns this result. When queryset is not Empty.
*emphasized text*
    [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "SKU": 11,
            "name": "Item_11",
            "type": "paper",
        },

```
]
```

But I want to show the result with the response code. like this.....

```
    [
        {
            "response_code": "200",
            "response": "200",
            "message": "Ok"
        }

        {
            "id": 6,
            "SKU": 11,
            "name": "Item_11",
            "type": "paper",

        },
 ]
```